# Routing with parameters

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have a NewsPage controller. It's responsible for displaying a list of news and when typing the news id in the url also the specific news. Therefore I have the following url_handler within the controller:

```
class NewsPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {

  private static $url_handlers = array(
      'rss' => 'rss',
      '$ID!' => 'news'
  );
```

And the allowed_action:

```
private static $allowed_actions = array('rss', 'news');


public function news(SS_HTTPRequest $request) {

     $paramElement = $request->allParams();
..
```

At the moment it works that when I put the URL:

```
domain.com/news -> I get a list of all available news.
domain.com/news/123 -> I get a specific news
domain.com/news/rss -> I get the rss feed with all the available news
```

I put in the config.yml:

```
'news//': 'NewsPage_Controller'
```

But when i type `domain.com/news/123/1235` my site is shown 2 times in the frontend. In fact it should not be possible to write to times an id..

Is there something missing in the `$url_handlers`?

My Controller:

```
<?php

class NewsPage extends Page {
private static $db = array(
);
private static $has_one = array(
);
private static $has_many = array(
    'News' => 'News'
);

}

class NewsPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {

private $id;
private static $allowed_actions = array('news', 'rss');
private static $url_handlers = array(
    'rss' => 'rss',
    '' => 'index',
    '$Slug' => 'news'
);

public function init() {
    RSSFeed::linkToFeed($this->Link("rss"), "RSS feed");
    parent::init();
}

public function rss() {
    // Creates a new RSS Feed list

    $rss = new RSSFeed(
            $list = $this->getNewsList(), // an SS_List containing your feed items
            $link = $this->Link("rss"), // a HTTP link to this feed
            $title = "My feed", // title for this feed, displayed in RSS readers
            $description = "This is an example feed." // description
    );
    // Outputs the RSS feed to the user.
    return $rss->outputToBrowser();
}

public function news(SS_HTTPRequest $request) {
    var_dump($request->allParams());

    $paramElement = $request->allParams();

    $URLSegment = Convert::raw2sql($paramElement['Slug']);

    $this->id = $URLSegment;

    if (!($this->id)) {
        return $this->httpError(404, 'Sorry that product could not be found');
    }

    // Show the layout in the view
    $ssv = new SSViewer("Page");
    $ssv->setTemplateFile("Layout", "NewsDetailPage");
    echo $this->renderWith($ssv);
}

//Get news with specific id
public function getData() {
    $data = DataObject::get_one('News', "URLSegment = '" . $this->id . "'");
    if ($data == null) {
        return $this->httpError(404, 'Sorry that product could not be found');
    }
    return $data;
}

public function getNewsList() {
    $list = News::get();
    return $list;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be domain.com/NewsPageURL/news/123 ?

Comment: No, "news" is already the page type.. I made some modifications in my post above..

Comment: if you use url_handler you don't need the yml. Also, might be a type but seems that your view function isn't actually used?

Comment: By applying debug_request=1 on domain.com/news/123/12 i can see that the RequestHandler.php is executed 2 times. The first execution is ok, it simply applys the rule of $ID what refers to domain.com/news/123. What i don't understand is that it applies '$Action//$ID/$OtherID' what refers to domain.com/news/123/12 .. How can I avoid that this rule is applied $Action//$ID/$OtherID ? Thank you

Comment: When I remove the routing from the yml and just use 'rss' => 'rss', '$ID!' => 'news' within the url_handler i get after domain.com/news/123/12 the following error: [User Warning] popCurrent called on ModelAsController controller, but it wasn't at the top of the stack

Comment: (if you change things in statics or yml, remember to run ?flush.) Which SS version are you on by the way? Just to confirm, so there are no NewsPage in the cms with a URL right? You are just using NewsPage_Controller as a standalone controller? If so, it extending `ContentController` instead of just `Controller` could explain the issue you have with the OtherID rule being applied and the ModelAsController error.

Comment: Also, having `//` in your yml doesn't make sense I think, since it is a ShiftPoint for variable after it, and there are no vars in your yml rule. If you remove the yml rule altogether, you'll need to add news/ to the url_handler rules. Seeing the full controller code might help, can you post a gist or something?

Comment: I post my controller above. I removed all the routing in yml and put it within the $url_handlers.

Comment: I've created in the cms 1 page which is called "News" and is of type NewsPage. It uses a template were I show all news (function NewsList in this controller). There is an additional template for the detail news page which I render in the news function (template: NewsdetailPage).

Comment: if you have the page in the cms, you should not need the yml rule and neither news/ in your ur_handler if that's the page's urlsegment. For your multiple page rendering you might want to look at $this->render(...) instead of creating a new SSViewer etc...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I call: domain.com/news/rss/someString I get the following error message: "[User Warning] popCurrent called on ModelAsController controller, but it wasn't at the top of the stack. " How can I throwing an error page when after rss there is an unsupported string in the url. My url_handler contains: 'rss' => 'rss', '' => 'index', '$Slug' => 'news' - Thank you